# tabularray: Expand multiple macros

Tags: expansion, tabularray

I'm trying to build a `tblr` table and have multiple macros containing alignment characters expanded in it, like so:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\newcommand{\introrow}{Cat & Dog \\}
\newcommand{\outrorow}{Frog & Duck \\}


\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{cc}
    \introrow
    Crow & Hawk \\
    \outrorow
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

(Background: I'm trying to define an environment that provides the specifications for a table written by the user, and provides multiple building blocks in the form of macros that the user can insert as needed.)

This doesn't work as `tabularray` needs to see all alignment characters. By passing `expand=\introrow` or `expand=\outrorow`, I can fix this for one of my macros.

Is there a way to have the `tblr` environment expand *both* macros?
Adding two `expand` keys doesn't work.

Comment: Note. The author of the package says this feature will be supported in the future [expand multiple macros · Issue #77 · lvjr/tabularray](https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/issues/77)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a different answer than my other, which requires minimal changes from the OP's MWE.  Basically, instead of employing `\newcommand` to define his intro and outro, use `\newtoks`.  That way, one can use `[expand=\the]` to get both of them expanded inside of `tblr`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\newtoks\introrow
\newtoks\outrorow

\introrow{Cat & Dog \\}
\outrorow{Frog & Duck \\}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}[expand=\the]{cc}
    \the\introrow
    Crow & Hawk \\
    \the\outrorow
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 this is similar to mine but better:-)

Comment: Coming from you, @DavidCarlisle, that's a fine compliment.

Comment: Is it possible to add arguments to these functions? Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/675331/tabularray-expand-multiple-macros-with-background-color

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure this is playing the game as intended but

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\newcommand{\introrow}{Cat & Dog \\}
\newcommand{\outrorow}{Frog & Duck \\}



\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}[expand=\expandafter]{cc}
    \expandafter\empty\introrow
    Crow & Hawk \\
    \expandafter\empty\outrorow
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm impressed...

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik that isn't how you spell horrified

Comment: This looks like a horrible hack. I like it!
(Although the hack is visible to the user, making it slightly less elegant.)

Comment: I tried it but it fails to display colors on the first cell… See my post here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/675331/tabularray-expand-multiple-macros-with-background-color

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what kind of structure your `tblr` has, this may suffice.  Here, I employ a tokencycle to scan the tokens of the new `xtblr` environment, in search of control sequences.  Any token not a control sequence gets echoed to a token list.  The `\\` macro also gets echoed to the token list.  When any other control sequence is found, however, it is once expanded before being added to the token list.

Once the full environment content is so scanned, the token list is regurgitated as the argument to `tblr`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray,tokcycle,environ}

\newcommand{\introrow}{Cat & Dog \\}
\newcommand{\outrorow}{Frog & Duck \\}
\NewEnviron{xtblr}[1]{%
  \resettokcycle
  \Macrodirective{\ifx\\##1\addcytoks{##1}\else\addcytoks[1]{##1}\fi}%
  \expandafter\tokcyclexpress\expandafter{\BODY}%
  \begin{tblr}[expand=\the]{#1}\the\cytoks\end{tblr}%
}
\begin{document}

\begin{xtblr}{cc}
    \introrow
    Crow & Hawk \\
    \outrorow
\end{xtblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That's the great answer of lvjr ([here](https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/issues/77#issuecomment-1432264149), feel free to write your own answer if you want me to accept it), whose trick is to use `\expanded`. It even works with arguments:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\yes}{O{Yes}m}{\SetCell{bg=green9}#1}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\no}{O{No}m}{\SetCell{bg=red8}#1}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}[expand=\expanded]{cc}
  What I want               & is below              \\
  \SetCell{bg=green9} Yes   & \SetCell{bg=red8} No  \\
  \SetCell{bg=green9} Great & \SetCell{bg=red8} Bad \\
  What I get                & is below              \\
  \expanded{\yes{}}         & \expanded{\no{}}      \\
  \expanded{\yes[Great]{}}  & \expanded{\no[Bad]{}}
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

Note that you need to protect fragile commands (if any) inside them with `\unexpanded` command.