# tabularray: Macros & counters inside table

Tags: expansion, tabularray

Working with the `tabularray` package, I'm trying to use a macro that operates a counter inside a table, like so:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\newcounter{dbg}

\newcommand{\ctr}{\refstepcounter{dbg}\arabic{dbg}}

\ctr
\ctr
\ctr

\begin{tabular}{ccc}
    \ctr & \ctr & \ctr \\
    \ctr & \ctr & \ctr \\
\end{tabular}

\begin{tblr}{ccc}
    \ctr & \ctr & \ctr \\
    \ctr & \ctr & \ctr \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

The `\ctr` macro works fine outside of tables and in a regular `tabular`, but inside `tabularray`, the results are… surprisingly large.

[image: screenshot of LaTeX code shown above, showing a line with 1 2 3, a table with numbers 4 though 9, and a table with number 29, 32, 35, 38, 41, 44]

It looks like `tabularray` is expanding the macro multiple times internally.

The `\NewTableCommand` mechanism isn't allowed to produce cell text, so it doesn't seem to help me. There's the ([somewhat limited](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/617961/tabularray-expand-multiple-macros/618001)) `expand` option, but I haven't seen it have any effect on this, and neither did I find a way to sneak in a `\protect` or `\noexpand` to make it work.
Splitting the counting and printing into two commands, a `\NewTableCommand`-defined one that steps the counter and a regular one to print it *almost* works, but all the stepping is done before the table is set, so all cells show the final value of the counter.

Is there some way to get `tabularray` to expand my cells as intended?

Comment: the package evaluates the body multiple times for trial typesetting there is an issue in its github about that (I think something is added in the development source based on the mechanism tabularx uses to preserve counters)

Comment: https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/discussions/83  and linked issues

Comment: Thanks! That link actually contains the answer: `\UseTblrLibrary{counter}` loads code that fixes this (by storing and restoring counter values, I think). Do you want to post that as an answer yourself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package evaluates the body multiple times for trial typesetting there is an issue in its github about that. Code was added to allow preserving counters  based on the mechanism tabularx uses to preserve counters

https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/discussions/83 and linked issues

As shown there, in recent releases you can use

```
\UseTblrLibrary{counter}
```

which loads code that fixes this (by storing and restoring counter values).