# tabulararray: can't use def to set cell properties?

Tags: expansion, tabularray

in order to keep a coherant look in my tabular, I wanted to define a command like `\def\YES{\SetCell{bg=green9} YES}` to automatically add a green background when I type `\YES`. Unfortunately, it does not apply the background color:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}

{
  \def\YES{\SetCell{bg=green9} YES}
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tblr}{colspec={cc}}% Tried to use expand=\YES, does not work.
      \YES{} & fails but this works: & \SetCell{bg=green9} YES \\
    \end{tblr}
  \end{center}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: best to mention that you cross posted this as a gh issue https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/issues/157

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works for me:

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}

{
  \def\YES{\SetCell{bg=green9} YES}
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tblr}[expand=\YES]{colspec={cc}}% Tried to use expand=\YES, does not work.
      \YES & fails but this works: & \SetCell{bg=green9} YES \\
    \end{tblr}
  \end{center}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ohhh I was using expand=\YES as part of the mandatory argument, I did not realized it was inside an optional environment... thanks!

Comment: Hum... how would you expand multiple commands, like YES and no?

Comment: @tobiasBora well I would have put money on you asking that next. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/617982/1090

Comment: Ahah thanks ^^ Any reason such horrible hacks are necessary? I mean, wouldn't it be possible to ask to the tabularray team to implement it directly?

Comment: @tobiasBora they (I think actually a person not a team)  have an issue  tracker you could ask. But tables are tricky and the chosen design here is to read the table body without expansion while collecting the cells. (Probably to make it easier to re-run each cell multiple times with trial settings)

Answer (score 1):

For reference, that's the great answer of lvjr ([here](https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/issues/77#issuecomment-1432264149), feel free to write your own answer if you want me to accept it), whose trick is to use `\expanded` to do multiple macro expansions:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\yes}{O{Yes}m}{\SetCell{bg=green9}#1}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\no}{O{No}m}{\SetCell{bg=red8}#1}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}[expand=\expanded]{cc}
  What I want               & is below              \\
  \SetCell{bg=green9} Yes   & \SetCell{bg=red8} No  \\
  \SetCell{bg=green9} Great & \SetCell{bg=red8} Bad \\
  What I get                & is below              \\
  \expanded{\yes{}}         & \expanded{\no{}}      \\
  \expanded{\yes[Great]{}}  & \expanded{\no[Bad]{}}
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

Note that you need to protect fragile commands (if any) inside them with `\unexpanded` command.