# Tabularray: expand multiple macros with background color

Tags: tabularray

I'm trying to expand in tabularry multiple macros to automatically add different background colors, but the color is not taken into account:

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\yes}{O{Yes}m}{\SetCell{bg=green9} #1}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\no}{O{No}m}{\SetCell{bg=red8} #1}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}[expand=\expandafter]{cc}
  What I want & is below\\
  \SetCell{bg=green9} Yes & \SetCell{bg=red8} No\\
  \SetCell{bg=green9} Great & \SetCell{bg=red8} Bad\\
  What I get & is below\\
  \expandafter\empty\yes{} & \expandafter\empty\no{}\\
  \expandafter\empty\yes[Great]{} & \expandafter\empty\no[Bad]{}
\end{tblr}


\end{document}
```

Related, but don't fix my issue: [tabulararray: can't use def to set cell properties?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/624063/tabulararray-cant-use-def-to-set-cell-properties) [tabularray: Expand multiple macros](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/617961/tabularray-expand-multiple-macros)

Comment: expandable doesn't mean "expands in one step" (as you would need for \expandafter). Beside this: even if it would expand to \SetCell, it wouldn't work as there is still the \empty before, and something like `\empty\SetCell{bg=green9} Yes` doesn't work.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I see thanks… so there is no way to achieve what I want to do?

Comment: Do you need any text inside these macros or just to adjust the color?

Answer (score 4):

From the manual of `tabularray`:

[image]

So, NO optional argument. That's not possible. And only *one* macro can be expanded.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\newcommand{\yn}[2]{\SetCell{bg=\if#1ygreen9\else red8\fi}#2}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}[expand=\yn]{cc}
  What I want & is below\\
  \SetCell{bg=green9} Yes & \SetCell{bg=red8} No\\
  \SetCell{bg=green9} Great & \SetCell{bg=red8} Bad\\
  What I get & is below\\
  \yn{y}{Yes} & \yn{n}{No}\\
  \yn{y}{Great} & \yn{n}{Bad}
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A possibly better definition of `\yn` is

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \yn #1 #2
 {
  \SetCell{bg=\str_case:nn {#1}{{y}{green9}{n}{red8}}}#2
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

With standard methods:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{ninecolors}

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\yes}{O{Yes}m}{\cellcolor{green9}#1}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\no}{O{No}m}{\cellcolor{red8}#1}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cc}
  First & Second \\
  \yes{} & \no{}\\
  \yes[Great]{} & \no[Bad]{}
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks… but actually lvjr found a solution based on `\expanded` (I created a new answer below)

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need any text inside the commands, and just want a shorter macro name for `\SetCell{bg=red8}`, `tabularray` has the command `\NewTableCommand` for that (see section 3.6 and subsection 3.2.3 of the documentation):

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\NewTableCommand\yes{\SetCell{bg=green9}}
\NewTableCommand\no{\SetCell{bg=red8}}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tblr}{cc}
        What I want & is below\\
        \SetCell{bg=green9} Yes & \SetCell{bg=red8} No\\
        \SetCell{bg=green9} Great & \SetCell{bg=red8} Bad\\
        What I get & is below\\
         \yes Yes & \no No\\
        \yes Great & \no Bad
    \end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for this trick! (+1) But ideally I'd love to be able to add text as well.

Answer (score 1):

That's the great answer of lvjr ([here](https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/issues/77#issuecomment-1432264149), feel free to write your own answer if you want me to accept it), whose trick is to use `\expanded`:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\yes}{O{Yes}m}{\SetCell{bg=green9}#1}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\no}{O{No}m}{\SetCell{bg=red8}#1}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}[expand=\expanded]{cc}
  What I want               & is below              \\
  \SetCell{bg=green9} Yes   & \SetCell{bg=red8} No  \\
  \SetCell{bg=green9} Great & \SetCell{bg=red8} Bad \\
  What I get                & is below              \\
  \expanded{\yes{}}         & \expanded{\no{}}      \\
  \expanded{\yes[Great]{}}  & \expanded{\no[Bad]{}}
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

Note that you need to protect fragile commands (if any) inside them with `\unexpanded` command.